# Is the SOA a means to connect monoliths?

Tags: microservices, soa

Currently I am investigating the differences between Microservice Architecture and Service Oriented Architecture. A differentiating point is the Service.

In a MSA it is quite clear. A MSA consists of Microservices. They are doing one thing and doing it right. (vertical splitting in contrast to monolith)

For a SOA it is not so clear for me. I read in quite a lot of papers, that they are basically monoliths. (10.1109/HPCSim.2016.7568389 & 10.1109/ICITST.2016.7856721)

Somehow the picture does not really make sense for me. I had the perception that a SOA (like a MSA) should supersede the monolith?

I think it could relate to the fact that there is also a difference between the really old monolith (earlier 2000) and the monolith which gets split into Microservices.

Additional request: Does someone has a good definition for monolith?

**Q: Why is a SOA Service a monolith? In my eyes there should be a difference between a Service and a monolith.**

Comment: What picture are you referring to? I was able to find The ENTICE Approach to Decompose Monolithic Services into Microservices (10.1109/HPCSim.2016.7568389), which has several different figures in it. I was not able to find a freely available version of The evolution of distributed systems towards microservices architecture (10.1109/ICITST.2016.7856721). This may be very close to "explain this {blog/article}", though, since there isn't consensus on exactly what a "microservice" is or what "SOA" is, even though there are some fairly widely agreed-upon elements of both.

Comment: Sorry I am not a native english speaker. I mean picture in the metaphorical sense. The constellation I describe.

Answer (score 1):

Without reading the two papers mentioned (I could only find one freely available, anyway), the conception that a system built with a SOA-based architectural model is a monolith is incorrect.

A service-oriented architecture is centered on thinking about the service or services that a system provides to external clients in a manner that allows the clients to not care about the implementation details or inner workings of the services. That is, the system is a black box to clients. It says nothing about how the system is internally structured or deployed.

Microservices are an architectural approach to organizing the components of a system into independently deployable entities. There is often guidance around isolating the implementation, configuration, and data associated with each microservice to make it fully independent.

Each approach is looking at two different things. SOA is looking at the interactions between the system and clients. Microservices are about the interactions between components of the system. You can implement a service-oriented architecture using a microservices architecture or a monolithic architecture.

Within a monolithic architecture, there are good practices that help to isolate services that may be within a deployable entity. The [majestic monolith](https://m.signalvnoise.com/the-majestic-monolith/) is one such approach, and there is good advice that systems should generally [start out as a well-architected monolith](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html) before being refactored into microservices when necessary. These approaches also help to keep services within a monolith encapsulated, autonomous, and reusable.

Comment: I agree in most parts with your statement. May I phrased it not exactly enough. I don't see the SOA as an monolith. My question is if a single SOA Service is a monolith.

Comment: @krispy_k That depends on how many services your system provides and what the architecture of your system is. I don't see anything that would prevent that from happening. I don't see anything that would mandate that, either.

Comment: When I get you right you see it as a normal process that services pollute to monoliths? What differentiates the single SOA Service from a single Microservice?

Comment: @krispy_k I don't know what you mean by "services pollute to monoliths". In the context of a system, a single SOA service may be realized by a single microservice, or a single SOA service may be realized by many microservices. Similarly, a monolithic application may provide many different SOA services or a microservice-based application may provide many different SOA services. The client of a SOA service doesn't care about the architecture of the system, just that a service exists and conforms to the interface.

Comment: I mean when Services evolve (i.e. new requirements) they become monoliths when the boundaries are not clearly defined. In the times of SOA practices like DDD weren't used. Therefore the probability that a Service evolves to a monolith is high. Microservices in contrast mandate to split again. I agree that a SOA can consist of multiple Microservices/MSAs. Academia states that SOA has an enterprise scope and MSA an application scope. I don't understand the inverse case: a MSA which consists of SOA services. Could you please elaborate further on it? Thanks for your patience I appreciate it.

Comment: @krispy_k Not maintaining boundaries as requirements change has nothing to do with monoliths or microservices or SOA - that's poor decision making on the part of the team. The concept of a service "evolving" into a monolith makes no sense - if you don't maintain boundaries, your system will become a [big ball of mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud). As far as the rest, I honestly don't understand what your problem is. There's really nothing more I can say in the abstract, so unless you have a specific example of a real system, I can't provide any more general information.

Comment: @krispy_k: It seems pretty clear that you're overthinking this.  If you really want clear insight into these terms, stop reading papers and write some code.  Musing about vocabulary won't get you any closer to a working application.

Comment: Totally understand your point. I am currently writing a review about the differences and commonalities of both architectures. Therefore the whole questions. But you're right to dig deeper I need some code. Do you may have a reference to a good sample SOA?